# Multiple exception handlers for file processing

Tags: haskell, exception, io

I guess my brain is going soggy. Can somebody explain to be the best way to achieve the following task?

I want to open a file, do some stuff with it, and then close it. I want to ensure that in all circumstances, the file is definitely closed. I also want to run a particular I/O action if opening the file fails (does not exist, access denied, etc)

For cleanup, I presumably want `bracket`, and for handling the open failure I presumably want some variant of `try`. But I can't decide the best way to combine these so that it does the right thing, without leaving any "gaps" (places where an exception at the wrong moment could break stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `try` to open the file. If successful use `finally` to work with the file handle and close the file afterwards. If opening the file was not successful, go into your error case. So the code should look something like this:

```
do
  res <- try (openFile filename mode)
  case res of
    Right handle ->
      finally (workWith handle) (hClose handle)
    Left (e :: SomeException) ->
      handleOpeningError e
```

This will execute the `handleOpeningError` action if `openFile` failed and it will close the file handle under all circumstances. If an exception occurs during `workWith handle`, that exception will be re-thrown after the file handle has been closed (if I understood you correctly, you only want to handle exceptions that are thrown by `openFile` and otherwise you only want to ensure the file was closed).

Answer (score 1):

Here are three comments about doing file handling in Haskell:
http://newartisans.com/2013/05/three-examples-of-problems-with-lazy-io

The author suggests the use of one of the following approaches/libraries:

- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Conduit
- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pipe
- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library/Streams

Comment: Who said anything about _lazy_ I/O? I want a handle so I can read strict ByteStrings and do lots of seeking backwards and forwards. My impression is that the above libraries are intended for sequential access, not random access.